# jQuery dynamic selector for child - utterly confused

Tags: jquery, function, selector, parent

I have a two divs (#tweeta" and "#tweetb"). Each of these has a child div with the class ".container".

I'm trying to pass the div name dynamically in a function that writes some text into the ".container" div. Here is the function. This works when I reference one of the parent divs specifically like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
var itema = 0;
var itemsa = $('#my-tweets li:odd').length;

function tickInterval(curr, total, ID) {
    if(curr < total) {
        var text = $('#my-tweets li:odd:eq('+curr+')').html();
        $('#tweeta > .container').html(text);
        type(curr, total, text, ID);
    } else if(curr == total) {
        curr = 0;
        tickInterval(curr, total, ID);      
    }
}

tickInterval(itema, itemsa, tweeta);

});
```

However, when I try to swap out the explicit id with the variable "ID", either the function is applied to BOTH #tweeta AND #tweetb OR I get an error message ('Exception thrown and not caught')...

`$('#' + ID).children('.container').html(text);`

`$('#' + ID).find('.container').html(text);`

`$('#' + ID > '.container').html(text);`

`$('div[id='+ ID +'] > div').html(text);`

I'm very confused now, about the best way to select the '.container' div without writing the parent div id explicitly into the function.

If you can help me, I thank you!

Amal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot quotes around third parameter of your function, it should be:

```
tickInterval(itema, itemsa, 'tweeta');
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. Do you know of a tool that would pick up a mistake like this?